# How to start airflow-scheduler pod for Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

A Composer cluster went down because its airflow-worker pods needed a Docker image that was not accessible.

Now access to the Docker image was restore, but the **airflow-scheduler pod has disappeared**.

I tried updating the Composer Environment by setting a new Environment Variable, with the following error :

```
UPDATE operation on this environment failed X minutes ago with the following error message: (404)
Reason: Not Found
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({
  "Date": "recently",
  "Audit-Id": "my-own-audit-id",
  "Content-Length": "236",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache, private"
})
HTTP response body: {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "deployments.apps \"airflow-scheduler\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "airflow-scheduler",
    "group": "apps",
    "kind": "deployments"
  },
  "code": 404
}

Error in Composer Agent
```

How can I launch a airflow-scheduler pod on my Composer cluster ?

**What is the `.yaml` configuration file I need to apply ?**

I tried launching the scheduler from inside another pod with `airflow scheduler`, and while it effectively starts a scheduler, it's not a Kubernetes pod and will not integrate well with the managed airflow cluster.

Answer (score -1):

To restart the airflow-scheduler, run the following

```
# Fetch the old deployment, and pipe it into the replace command.
COMPOSER_WORKSPACE=$(kubectl get namespace | egrep -i 'composer|airflow' | awk '{ print $1 }')
kubectl get deployment airflow-scheduler --output yaml \
    --namespace=${COMPOSER_WORKSPACE}| kubectl replace --force -f -
```

Comment: The thing is the pod was deleted and I cannot retrieve the existing application file.

Comment: @vdolez Is the airflow-scheduler pod of your Composer environment currently operative?

Comment: You can suppose it's not. I was able to use and modify another application file for Kubernetes in order to launch it from another similar Composer environment, but I fear there're might be some differences between the cluster versions/connexions used.

Comment: @vdolez I see. Unfortunately, there is not a standard Kubernetes application file to launch an airflow-scheduler pod available. As a self-managed product, the Composer infrastructure is not meant to be tuned.

Comment: Isn't there a Kubernetes Executor for Airflow which requires such a Pod application yaml ?